# Help validating counter-example (basic probability - generated $\sigma$-algebra)

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading a (French) book on basic probability (Probabilités en vue des applications - Valérie Girardin, Nikolaos Limnios). I found the following assertion, without proof, in the part of the book dealing with $\sigma$-algebras and measurable spaces:

> For all subsets $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ of $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, we have:
>
> \begin{equation*}
> \sigma(\mathcal{C} \cup \mathcal{D}) = \sigma(\left\{ C \cup D \mid C \in \mathcal{C}, \, D \in \mathcal{D} \right\}) = \sigma(\left\{ C \cap D \mid C \in \mathcal{C}, \, D \in \mathcal{D} \right\})
> \end{equation*}

*The notation: $\sigma(A)$ means the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A \subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space.*

I believe I found a counter-example, and I would like someone to proof-read it:

Let: $\Omega = \left\{1,\, 2,\, 3\, \right\}$, and let $\mathcal{C} \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega),\, \mathcal{D} \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ be defined by $\mathcal{C} = \left\{1 \right\}$ et $\mathcal{D} = \left\{2 \right\}$. We have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\mathcal{C} \cup \mathcal{D} &= \left\{ \left\{1 \right\}, \left\{2 \right\} \right\} \\
\sigma(\mathcal{C} \cup \mathcal{D}) &= \mathcal{P}(\Omega) \\
&\\
\left\{ C \cup D \mid C \in \mathcal{C}, \, D \in \mathcal{D} \right\} &= \left\{ \left\{1, \,2 \right\} \right\} \\
\sigma(\left\{ C \cup D \mid C \in \mathcal{C}, \, D \in \mathcal{D} \right\}) &= \left\{\, \varnothing,\, \left\{1,\, 2 \right\},\, \left\{ 3 \right\},\, \Omega \right\} \\
&\\
\left\{ C \cap D \mid C \in \mathcal{C}, \, D \in \mathcal{D} \right\} &= \varnothing \\
\sigma(\left\{ C \cap D \mid C \in \mathcal{C}, \, D \in \mathcal{D} \right\}) &= \left\{\, \varnothing,\, \Omega \right\}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Do you spot a mistake in my reasonning ?

Comment: "Tribus" is translated to "$\sigma$-algebra" in English. The word "tribe" means something completely different.

Comment: Your counterexample is correct. It is not surprising that you have found a mistake in a textbook. I have read dozens of math textbooks in the course of my studies and there is not a single one that has no errors. You must never expect to be fed the material with a silver spoon. Reading a math textbook is an active endeavor. You should constantly question the validity of what you're reading and keep a pen and a notepad near by to do calculations and check proofs.

Comment: @EvanAad Thanks for your comment and editing. I understand that I need to actively work when reading math textbook. Maybe my last sentence is offending, I didn't mean it to be, and I will remove it.